# Can I lock some tables from my Oracle Apex Application? (Oracle APEX 21.1)

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a question about creating my application. It is about locking records.

Users can perform updates of the cats list with the CSV upload function and on the screen.
But I am afraid that during the CSV upload, they will edit nickname of cats or their favorite snacks from the screen.
I want to lock the records until the CSV upload is complete.(As a side note, now this application  have about 20 cats registered.)

How can I do that? In SQL? Or some configuration of Oracle APEX?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APEX is a stateless application. That means that all transactions are committed "immediately" (well explained [here](https://tedstruik-oracle.nl/ords/f?p=25384:1065:)). "locking rows" isn't probably what you want. Have a look at the concept of "Lost update detection" there are multiple ways to implement that in APEX / the oracle database.

Comment: Great! I read "Lost update detection" in Oracle Docs. This will help me. Thank you!!!!